# SEO Google - Navigation Title vs. Page Heading

Tags: optimization, seo, search-engine

i was wondering if anyone knows if there's a connection between what a navigation item is named and the page heading it goes to - does this have an impact on SEO?

so for example, if i had in my navigation menu an item called **About Us**, but when you click it you come to a page with the heading **Learn Who We Are** (i.e. wrapped in [h1] heading tags)

because there isn't an exact one-to-one match, is that a bad thing in terms of SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not at all. In fact it can be beneficial in some cases because Google picks up the text used in links as keywords for that page. So in theory your page could appear in SERPs for the phrase 'About Us'.

If Google's algorithms decide that your 'learn who we are' page is not at all related to the phrase 'about us' then the phrase may not count much *as keywords*. But you won't be penalised or lose ranking.

Incidentally, keywords in links don't think it carry as much weight as they used to, because of [Google Bombing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb).